# What is most appropriate way to read all data from a text file in one go?

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I have a text file and I want to read the entire contents of it into a String variable. **The file is being opened as an InputStream as I am using Android's `assetManager.open()` method.**

What is the best practise way to read the entire contents into a String? I am currently wrapping the InputStream with an InputStreamReader and then a BufferedReader and using a while loop I read in the text line by line with the readLine() method.

Is there a better way of reading in this text considering I there is no requirement to read it in line by line, I'd like to get it all in one go if possible

Comment: `new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")` with explicit encoding parameter is fine. @assylias tip of `Files.readAllLines` is nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One normally should not reinvent the wheel, so use the apache commons library, if the overhead is bearable on Android.
Use [org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("a.txt"));
String s = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what [Java 7 `Files.readAllLines` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/nio/file/Files.java#Files.readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path%2Cjava.nio.charset.Charset%29) does - I would expect it to be a very good way of doing it (it uses a try-with-resources syntax which is easily transposable to work on android):

```
public static List<String> readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = newBufferedReader(path, cs)) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (;;) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            result.add(line);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In your case, you could append the strings to a StringBuilder instead of adding them to a list.

Comment: The Android AssetManager only opens the file as an InpuStream so that's what I'm working with.

Comment: Is there another way of accessing assets in Android just using paths? I can't see the point of having an AssetManager class in the first place if it's not to enforce a strict method for accessing the apps' assets?

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible way of doing it.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a.txt"));
char[] cbuf = new char[500];
br.read(cbuf);
String fileContents = new String(cbuf);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, encoding);      
scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
if (!scanner.hasNext()) {       // corner case -- file is empty
    return "";
}
String result = scanner.next();
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Scanner class

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);  
String content = scan.next();
```

Comment: This scans the next token and not the entire file.